# Shiny App no longer linking to www folder (CSS and images)

Tags: css, r, shiny

I created a shiny app and was working perfectly but I had included server in the same file.
I created a separate server.R, copied over the server.R code and sourced to server.R from ui.R.
Since then the app runs but it's no longer picking up CSS or images from the www folder.
Any ideas why this would happen?

```
source("global.R")
source("server.R")

# UI section 

ui <- navbarPage(
  tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style.css")),
  theme = shinytheme("simplex"),
  
  title = div(img(src="logo.jpeg", id = "logo"), "Location Performance Analysis - Google Analytics"),
```

[image: folder_structure]

Comment: What is your folder structure like? Are the `style.css` and `logo.jpeg` in the same directory as your `server.R`?

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I've added screen shot, www folder is in the root folder.

Comment: You might need to use `href = "www/style.css")`

Comment: I had tried that -  makes no difference :-(

Comment: There is no need to `source("global.R"); source("server.R")` shiny handles those files automatically.

Comment: Remove the first two lines from `ui.R` (no need to source `server.R` and `global.R`).  If that does not work, create a new file named `app.R` which has just two lines of code `library(shiny);
shinyApp(ui, server)`

Comment: Brill thanks, I should have had an app.R. - working perfectly now